# web app development using flask and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pycharm

I am developing a login form using flask version 1.0.2 in python 3.6 and HTML in Pycharm IDE but the problem is when i edit python code in app.py file i expect the changes to take effect and when i run on default url, http://127.0.0.1:5000/, it does not show the changes in the browser.The old first output keeps being printed.

I have deleted cache and cookies and browser history from all browsers plus using CNTRL + F5 for hard refresh but the problem has persisted.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'men what are you doing !'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What could be the problem?**

Comment: Please, could you add some code so we can reproduce this problem ?

Comment: Are you restarting the server? If not then you may not have debug mode enabled which makes the server auto restart on change. If you restart the server does it show your changes?

Comment: `app.run(host,port,debug=True)`

Comment: the original code looks like this                                                                          
 from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'men what are you doing !'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()   but i edited this line of code to app.run(port=8080) and the browser updates

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/server/#in-code

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set enviroment variable `FLASK_ENV` to `development` (default to `production`) to enable debug mode:

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development  # use > set ... on Windows
```

In debug mode, the reloader was enabled to detect file changes and reload the server.

Comment: also it is possible to do `app.debug=True`, or pass it as a parameter in `app.run(debug=True)`

Comment: You are right, but it is not recommended to directly set the `app.debug` and `FLASK_DEBUG` since Flask 1.0. Besides, the `app.run()` was not recommended too since Flask 0.11, see the [changlog](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/changelog/#version-0-11) for more information.